# Actualização de opções de campo baseado numa selecção com Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-eloquent, html-select

A partir [deste artigo](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-dynamic-dependant-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-example-part-2example.html) encontrei uma forma interessante de criar caixas de selecção dinâmicas. Consegui adaptá-lo ao meu caso, acrescentando a rotas/web.php

```
Route::post('select-ajax', ['as'=>'select-ajax','uses'=>'SpecificController@myformAjax']);
```

e gerar caixas de selecção dinâmicas que teriam como valores o `organization_id` como o seguinte estava no meu controlador

```
public function myformAjax(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        $campusorganizations = DB::table('campus_organizations')->where('campus_id',$request->campus_id)->pluck("organization_id","id")->all();
        $data = view('ajax-select',compact('campusorganizations'))->render();
        return response()->json(['options'=>$data]);
    }
}
```

e este foi o `ajax-select.blade.php`.

```
@if(!empty($campusorganizations))
  @foreach($campusorganizations as $key => $value)
    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

e o AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select[name='campus_id']").change(function(){
        var campus_id = $(this).val();
        var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo route('select-ajax') ?>",
            method: 'POST',
            data: {campus_id:campus_id, _token:token},
            success: function(data) {
                $("select[name='campus_organization_id'").html('');
                $("select[name='campus_organization_id'").html(data.options);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Este foi o resultado

[image]

---

A questão é que eu quero ter o nome da organização em vez do seu ID.

Dado que no meu modelo `CampusOrganization` tenho

```
/**
 * Get the organization
 *
 * @return \Organization
 */
public function organization()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Organization::class);
}
```

de onde posso obter o nome da organização.

Assim, adaptei o `ajax-select.blade.php` para

```
<option value=''>None</option>
@if(!empty($campusorganizations))
  @foreach($campusorganizations as $campusorganization)
    <option value="{{ $campusorganization->id }}">{{ $campusorganization->organization->name }}</option>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

e o controlador para

```
/**
 * Get Ajax Request and return Data
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function myformAjax(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){

        $campusorganizations = CampusOrganization::where('campus_id',$request->campus_id)->get();

        $data = view('rooms.ajax-select', $campusorganizations)->render();

        return response()->json(['options'=>$data]);
    }
}
```

mas agora tudo o que recebo é (sem opções)

[image]

Também testei com

```
$campusorganizations = CampusOrganization::with('organization')->where('campus_id',$request->campus_id)->get();
```

mas também não foram dados quaisquer resultados.

---

### Edit

Se eu retornar `$campusorganizations`

```
/**
 * Get Ajax Request and return Data
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function myformAjax(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){

        $campusorganizations = CampusOrganization::with('organization:id,name')
                                ->where('campus_id',$request->campus_id)
                                ->with('organization')
                                ->get();

        return $campusorganizations;

        $data = view('rooms.ajax-select',$campusorganizations)->render();

        return response()->json(['options'=>$data]);
    }
}
```

então verei na resposta

```
[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "campus_add_users": 0,
    "campus_id": 4,
    "organization_id": 4,
    "created_at": "2021-03-12T20:15:42.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-03-12T20:15:42.000000Z",
    "organization": {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Aldi",
      "slug": "aldi",
      "is_visible": 1,
      "user_id": 2,
      "created_at": "2021-03-12T20:15:38.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-03-12T20:15:38.000000Z"
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Depois de remover `return $campusorganizations;`, então a resposta será

```
{"options":"<option value=''>None<\/option>\r\n"}
```

[image]

---

Note que ao responder a esta pergunta poderás também responder às seguintes (posso ajudar tanto com o inglês e com o espanhol)

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/66652922/5675325
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/435853/108660

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No controlador, em vez de

```
$data = view('rooms.ajax-select',$campusorganizations)->render();
```

deves nomear a variável desta forma

```
$data = view('rooms.ajax-select',['campusorganizations'=>$campusorganizations])->render();
```

Isso vai ser suficiente

[image]